# Driving car in Toronto on Australian Drivers License

Tags: canada, driving, driving-licenses, australian-citizens, toronto

Just wanted to know if I can legally drive a car in Toronto, Canada on an Australian drivers license?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, if you are just visiting and not becoming a resident of Ontario.  In addition, depending on your length of visit, you may need an International Drivers' Permit in addition to your Australian licence.  From the [Ontario Ministry of Transportation](https://www.ontario.ca/page/drive-ontario-visitors):

> **Visiting: less than 3 months**
>
> If you are visiting Ontario for less than 3 months and want to drive while you're here, you can use a valid driver's licence from your own province, state or country.
>
> You will also need to:
>
> - be at least 16 years old
> - have proper insurance coverage for the vehicle you will drive
> - carry an original (or exact) copy of the vehicle ownership permit
> - obey traffic laws, drive safely and avoid collisions when you drive
>
> **Visiting: more than 3 months**
>
> If you will be visiting from another country for more than 3 months, you will need an International Driver's Permit (IDP) from your own country.
>
> This is a special licence that allows motorists to drive internationally when accompanied by a valid driver’s licence from their country.
>
> You need to have this permit with you when you arrive in Ontario. You cannot apply for one once you are here.